# VueJS 2 Cli converting POST to GET requests using Dev Server

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

### Issue

I started a new VueJS project using the Vue CLI. I'm using fetch to POST login info to a remote DEV server. When I call this method on my local environment it processes this call as a GET then a POST then a OPTIONS then a GET.

*This is what the network panel from Chrome shows after I run the POST request.*

[image]

When it hits the api server it is being processes as a GET request which is returns a 405 as it is a POST not a GET.

#### Question

Why is it bouncing between two 301s and then converting the call to a GET request.

---

#### Tools

I'm using VueJS 2 CLI, Webpack, and Babel

> Note: I replaced the real api url and server with a fake one

#### JavaScript Fetch method

```js
authenticate (username, password) {
  const url = '/api/login/authenticate/'
  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }).then(res => res.json());
}
```

#### Webpack API Proxy Setup

```
proxyTable: {
   "/api": "http://www.myDevServer.net"
}
```

Comment: What library are you using to fetch?

Comment: I'm using the polyfill whatwg-fetch https://github.com/github/fetch as my browser supports fetch natively the polyfill does not seem to be the issue.

Comment: Where are you seeing the network requests, ie what is the screenshot from? What is the `Location` header for those 301 responses?

Comment: Hmm, try `url = '/api/login/authenticate` **without** the trailing slash. Your server may interpret `/authenticate/` as a directory request

Comment: That could be, I’ll try that when I get back in the office.

Comment: Tried `/api/login/authenticate` and the location header is pointing to where I want it to go. Still no change.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work when I changed the Webpack API Proxy Setup to match [this](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html) pattern. I have not yet found docs on `changeOrigin` but it seems self explanatory.

#### Corrected Webpack API Proxy Setup

```
proxyTable: {
   "/api": {
      target: "http://www.myDevServer.net",
      changeOrigin: true
   }
}
```

What I'm guessing happened was I called a proxy that changed origin. As the proxy server didn't allow this so it returned a `301`. As the server was not there it didn't allow `POST` requests. Then the proxy tried to see what options were available, so it sent an `OPTIONS` call. It saw `GET` was allowed and called it. The `GET` was trying to process under my `POST` call and it failed as the format was wrong which returned a `405`